# Creating different Attributes with the same names

Tags: android, android-view, android-xml, android-resources, android-attributes

I am creating a class very similar to the `BottomSheetBehavior` and as such I wanted to maintain the same attribute names in my own `attrs.xml` to have consistency, but Android Studio is complaining about it:

> Android resource compilation failed Output: 
>   C:\Projects\MyProject\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1724:
>   error: **duplicate value for resource 'attr/behavior_peekHeight' with
>   config ''.**
>   C:\Projects\MyProject\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1724:
>   **error: resource previously defined here.**

Is it there a way to use the same attribute name for two different `View` classes?

[This](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/res/values/attrs.xml) is the `BottomSheetBehavior` `attrs.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="BottomSheetBehavior_Layout">        
        <attr name="behavior_peekHeight" format="dimension">            
            <enum name="auto" value="-1"/>
        </attr>        
        <attr name="behavior_hideable" format="boolean"/>        
        <attr name="behavior_skipCollapsed" format="boolean"/>
        <attr name="behavior_fitToContents" format="boolean"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

This is the `attrs.xml` file I wanted for `MyBehavior`:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MyBehavior_Layout">        
        <attr name="behavior_peekHeight" format="dimension">            
            <enum name="auto" value="-1"/>
        </attr>        
        <attr name="behavior_hideable" format="boolean"/>        
        <attr name="behavior_skipCollapsed" format="boolean"/>
        <attr name="behavior_fitToContents" format="boolean"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I tried what pskink said in the comments, to use `<attr name="android:behavior_hideable" />` :

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MyBehavior_Layout">
        <attr name="android:behavior_peekHeight" >              
            <enum name="auto" value="-1"/>
        </attr>
        <attr name="android:behavior_hideable" />
        <attr name="android:behavior_skipCollapsed" />
        <attr name="android:behavior_fitToContents" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

It still doesn't work, I get the error:

> Android resource linking failed
>
> Output:
>
> C:\Projects\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1724:
>   error: resource android:attr/behavior_peekHeight not found.
>
> C:\Projects\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1729:
>   error: resource android:attr/behavior_hideable not found.
>
> C:\Projects\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1731:
>   error: resource android:attr/behavior_skipCollapsed not found.
>
> C:\Projects\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1733:
>   error: resource android:attr/behavior_fitToContents not found. 
>   error:
>   failed linking references.

Comment: sure: use for example: `<attr name="android:background"/>` - note there is no `format` here

Comment: So in my `<declare-styleable name="MyBehavior_Layout">` I should place `<attr name="android:behavior_peekHeight" format="dimension">` ? I tried it and it didn't work, I get the error: `resource android:attr/behavior_peekHeight not found.`

Comment: What are the implications of not having a `format`? Is it implicitly copying the same attibute? If positive so I can't have the same attribute name with a different `format`?

Comment: did you try `<attr name="android:background"/>`?

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: this is my 30 seconds googling: https://medium.com/@elye.project/better-way-of-declaring-custom-view-attributes-23f876c28534

Comment: I tried to google for it, found several stackoverflow solutions, mostly on Rebuild and Invalidate Cache, but anyway, this medium article is blocked to me, apparently I used all my quota...I will try to read it in another device I have somewhere

Comment: here is another article: http://androidbook.com/item/4169

Comment: and no, `behavior_hideable` is not declared in `android` namespace - it belongs to `design` namespace/package - i gave you an example of existing `background` attribute that was created in `android` namespace

Comment: I finished reading the first article, very interesting thank you, I fixed it. First I realized `android:` was not possible since as you said `behavior_hideable` isn't in the `android` namespace, so I removed it. But in order to really fix it I had to remove the `enum` inside `behavior_peekHeight`, since it was a declaration of the type of `behavior_peekHeight` and in order for it to work I can only pass a reference, since it was already defined elsewhere.